# EJB Websocket Handshake Error: Response code was not 101: 404

Tags: java, websocket, jboss, ejb, java-websocket

If you don't have time to read the details, my problem in summary is:

### I get Http Error Code 404 when a simple websocket request send to `EJB Websocket Endpoint Server` in an *`ejb module`*

### (project created by maven with java8, EJB3 and JBOSS EAP 7.2)

Note that ejb module could not have neither *`web.xml`* nor *`maven contextRoot tag`*

### Details:

I have developed an enterprise project with EJB3 and deployed it by JBOSS-EAP7.2 using maven in IntellijIdea.
I need to provide a websocket server and client to communicate with third parties. some of codes provided as follows:

**Server-Side:**

```
@ServerEndpoint("/chat")
public class ChatServer {
    private Session session;

    @OnOpen
    public void connect(Session session){
        this.session=session;
    }

    @OnClose
    public void close(){
        this.session=null;
    }
    
    @OnMessage
    public void processMessage(String msg){
        System.out.println("msg = " + msg);;
        if(this.session!=null && this.session.isOpen()){
            try {
                this.session.getBasicRemote().sendText("this is from server");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

also at the server we have this class to declare a root path (and also enable our JAX-RS):

```
@ApplicationPath("gateway")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
    // without any implementation
}
```

Furthermore, I have a Filter at server-side as follows that do nothing for websocket requests and while debugging it is shown that the request is received at filter but after that server generate 400 and request never go to `ServerEndpoint`!

**Http Filter:**

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class SecurityFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {
    //some snipet to evaluate the JAX-RS and nothing to do with websocket requests
    //websocket request received here but it did not go toward EndpointServer
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext, ContainerResponseContext containerResponseContext) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("response status: "+ containerResponseContext.getStatus());
        //here I get Http status code 404 
    }
}
```

I removed the filter but the error still exists.

**Client-Side:**

```
public class SocketSmokeTest {
    private WebSocketContainer container;
    private HelloEndpoint endpoint;

    @Test
    public void communicate() {
        try {
            Session connectToServer = container.connectToServer
            (this.endpoint, new URI("ws://127.0.0.1:8080/gateway/chat"));
            //I have tried other path like "ws://127.0.0.1:8080/rootsource/gateway/chat"
            //or "ws://127.0.0.1:8080/rootsource/chat"
            this.endpoint.sendMessage("hello from client");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DeploymentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`HelloEndPoint` is a simple class as follows:

```
public class HelloEndpoint extends Endpoint {
    private Session session;

    @Override
    public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig endpointConfig) {
        this.session = session;

        this.session.addMessageHandler(new MessageHandler.Whole<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(String message) {
                System.out.println("!!!!!!  retrieved message: " + message);
            }
        });
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message){
        try {
            this.session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Error:** Running the SmokeTest gets this error:

> javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Handshake error.
>
> Caused by: org.glassfish.tyrus.core.HandshakeException: Response code was not 101: 404.

**wireshark Captured Data:**

```
GET /resources/websocket/chatserver/ HTTP/1.1
Connection: Upgrade
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8080
Sec-WebSocket-Key: K3mTSnyiVbi5/yeyIwFR2Q==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Upgrade: websocket

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sat, 05 Sep 2020 05:02:43 GMT
```

More information about project structure:
project consist of some modules in multiple-tier approach such as Data(ejb module), Business(ejb module), Gateway(ejb module), GUI(war module) that aggregate in an EAR. All JAX-RS and Websocket reside in Gateway module.

**EAR pom file:**

```
...
<dependencies>
    ...
</dependencies>
<build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <modules>
                        <ejbModule>
                            <groupId>ir.co.isc</groupId>
                            <artifactId>BusinessLayer</artifactId>
                        </ejbModule>
                        <ejbModule>
                            <groupId>ir.co.isc</groupId>
                            <artifactId>DataAccessLayer</artifactId>
                        </ejbModule>
                        <ejbModule>
                            <groupId>ir.co.isc</groupId>
                            <artifactId>PresentationLayerGateway</artifactId>
                        </ejbModule>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>ir.co.isc</groupId>
                            <artifactId>PresentationLayerGUI</artifactId>
                            <contextRoot>/rootsource</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
...
```

**Gateway EJB Module pom file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>Azmoonyar</artifactId>
        <groupId>ir.co.isc</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>PresentationLayerGateway</artifactId>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <name>PresentationLayerGateway</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ir.co.isc</groupId>
            <artifactId>BusinessLayer</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ejb/ejb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.websocket-client-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
            <artifactId>tyrus-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tyrus-standalone-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <ejbVersion>3.0</ejbVersion>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version   >
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: How is your web app deployed? What *context path* is specified during deployment?

Comment: Don't post code in a comment. Edit the question and show the pom there, nicely formatted.

Comment: Dear @Andreas you can see the updated question...

Comment: `/resources/websocket/chatserver` and `/resources/websocket/chatserver/` are two different end-points. Your code implements the first, but the request is for the second, so it is not found (404).

Comment: Javadoc of [`@ServerEndpoint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpoint.html#value--): *"The URI or URI-template, level-1 (See RFC 6570) where the endpoint will be deployed. The URI us relative to the root of the web socket container and **must begin with a leading "/"**. Trailing "/"'s are ignored."*

Comment: Dear @Andreas I have tried again as you mentioned with a leading slash (as I updated the code in the question), however the problem exists!